# Table and Form in the same page

Tags: forms, theming

I have a quick question. I work with a form that consists of the following:

```
$form['data_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Killer search engine!'),
    '#id'   => 'killer-search-engine',
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
    '#description' => t('Search by using tags and free text'),
);

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Go!!',
);
...
...
fill $table
...
...
if(sizeof($form_state['input'])!=0) {

    $form['table'] = array (
        '#title' => 'TABLE',
        '#type'   => 'table',
        '#value' => $table,
    );
}
return $form.
```

The form is appearing but the table element of it, even though it is filled with html code of an actual table(I checked through dpm($form)) does not appear.
Anyone with a quick fix?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display the values in table format you can use Table theme
Example:-

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('Empty Rows')
  );
```

`$header` and `$rows`  would be arrays.